# elsarticle / how to share lastauthor ship place among two authors

Tags: elsarticle, author, authorindex

how do I share last-authorship place in elsarticle authorlist among two authors?

The following MWE code:

```
\documentclass[review]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{lineno}
\modulolinenumbers[5]

\journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{Elsevier \LaTeX\ template\tnoteref{mytitlenote}}

%%
%% the question refers to the part below ---v
%%

%% Group authors per affiliation:
\author[1]{Corresponding author\corref{cor1}}
\ead{nomail}
\author[1]{co-author I}
\author[1]{co-author II}
\ead[url]{magic universities do not have a web address}
\author[1]{co-author III}
\author[2]{co-author IV}
\author[2,3]{co-author V}
\author[2]{co-author VI}


\cortext[cor1]{Corresponding author}

\address[1]{
    Hogwarts School of Witchcraft and Wizardry,  Institute for Magic Potions,   Hogwarts, UK
}
\address[2]{
    New York School of Witchcraft and Wizardry,  Institute for Protection against dark forces, New York, USA
}
\address[3]{
    Peking School of Witchcraft and Wizardry,  Institute for Magic, Peking, China
}

\begin{abstract}
This template helps you to create a properly formatted \LaTeX\ manuscript.
\end{abstract}

\begin{keyword}

\end{keyword}

\end{frontmatter}

\linenumbers

\section{The Elsevier article class}

\bibliography{mybibfile}

\end{document}
```

generates this output:
[image]

How do I achieve to place two authors in the last position and concatenate their names with a "&" or "and" to emphasize their equal contribution in that work? Please note that one author has one additional affiliation (co-author V vs co-author VI), otherwise I would just use one `\author` tag and include two, e.g. `\author[2]{co-author IV & co-author V}%\fnref{fn4}}`.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I wouldn't use an idiosyncratic notation that people are not used to, but rather add a "contributions" section explaining who contributed what. If I see an ampersand joining the last two elements of a list, then this is just the usual convention of using "and" between the last two elements of a list, nothing more.

Comment: thanks. The contributions section already mentions this in detail. It was just asked.